# Streaming an IP camera in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, streaming, ip-camera

I am trying to obtain video from an IP camera Axis 6034E using OpenCV in c++.
I can easily read stream using following simple code:

```
VideoCapture vid;
vid.open("http://user:password@ipaddres/mjpg/video.mjpg");
Mat frame;
while(true){
  vid.read(frame);
  imshow("frame", frame)
  waitKey(10);
}
```

But my problem is, the password contain `@` and unfortunately it is the last charterer of the password. Any idea I will appreciate it. 
I tried `\@` and some other encoding methods and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the @ in the password with `%40`?

Comment: No I hadn't, but it didn't works either.

Comment: Where's the error ? on `open()` or on `read()` ?

Comment: `open()` It can't read stream because `VideoCapture` think the password is wrong.

Comment: can you open that camera with VLC player?

Comment: Yeah, It tried with `cvlc` command lines and it works. But reading stream with VLC and convert it to `Mat` OpenCV is a little tricky and I prefer not to do that. This will be my last choice.